# Are there more than one origins of Ma Kali?

Tags: puranas, shiva-purana, parvati, devi, kali

There are multiple stories related to the origin of Goddess Mahakali:

1. The **Rudra Samhita 2.53** of the **Shiva Mahapuran** mentions that when Nandi informed Shiva about Sati's death, he became very furious. He angrily pulled out a locks of hair and dashed it against the mountain, which got divided into two parts. From one part manifested the valiant Veerbharda and from the other part Mahakali.
2. In the **Uma Samhita 5.16** of the same Puran Bhagawati manifested herself in the form of Kali from the mouth and eyes of lord Vishnu at the time Madhu and Kaitabh are born from Vishnu’s ear-wax and attack Brahma.
3. According to **Matsya Puran** Kali emerged when Parvati meditated to become fair and a goddess named Koushiki emerged out of her cells.
4. And then of course are the accounts in **Devi Mahatmya** and **Devi Bhagwat Puran** regarding her emerging from the forehead of Goddess Ambika.

**So do these different stories refer to different Kalis or to the different times Kali emerged? Also which of these appearances could be the oldest one?**

Comment: Kali that appeared from hair of Shiva was Bhadra Kali, not Mahaa Kali. Bhadra Kali is different than Kaal Ratri (Kali, form of Aadi Shakti) as per my knowledge.

Comment: Cool but what about the other stories?

Comment: This question is inherently linked to your other question about chronology of Kalpas.

Comment: Hmmm partially yes.. not sure whether the story of Madhu and Kaitabh is way before Sati and Parvati or it is just one of the anomalies of Kalpa Bheda. Also there are other version like that of Linga Puran that talks about a different origin of Kali from Parvati. I wish someone could post something helpful for either of the questions.

Comment: IMO All these are just appearances of Kali, who is eternal, into the mortal world. Sometimes she emerges from Vishnu, Shiva or Uma but none of these are her origin. It's just like Brahma appearing to bless the asuras. Srimad Bhagavatam refers to her as the creative power which awakens the dormant Narayana from his slumber, and causes his energy to pervade the elements. Thus she is as much eternal as is Narayana.

Comment: Hmmm so then the first story would be that of her emerging at the time of Madhu and Kaitabh.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Yes chronologically, it seems to be the first instance in the Kalpa when she manifests herself.